# How to select one specific cell inside an HTML table using JS/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

[calendar month with 5 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Z5u.png)
[calendar month with 6 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOQG2.png)

I am creating a dynamic calendar using HTML (table)s and JavaScript; I want to resize the height and width of the table cells depending on whether a specific month needs 5 or 6 rows to display the entire month.

I want to select the cell in an HTML table using JavaScript/jQuery so I can use its cell text in a conditional statement to resize the calendar. The code block needs to look something like this:

```
var td = $(td) // selects all <td> elements

var tdCheck6 = $(...) // selects cell text of cell in 1st row and 6th column
var tdCheck7 = $(...) // selects cell text of cell in 1st row and 7th column 

/* using Monday as the first day of the week, if (Saturday is the first day 
of one particular month AND the month has 31 days) OR (Sunday is the first day 
of the month AND the month has more than 29 days: that month will need 6 rows) */

if ((tdCheck6 == "1" && daysInMonth == 31) || (tdCheck7 == "1" && daysInMonth > 29)) {
     td.style.cssText = "height: 100px; width: 14.29%;";
} 
// use default cell dimensions for 5 rows
else {
     td.style.cssText = "height: 120px; width: 14.29%;"; 
}
```

By checking these conditions the calendar will refit the calendar viewport to fit 5 or 6 rows depending on the month.

Comment: document.getElementById("tableid").rows[0].cells[0].innerText; should do the trick (see: [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_cells)) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `:nth-child() Selector` in Jquery

Example: `$("td:nth-child(1)").text()`

For more details
https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/